# Authenticity of publications of Human Rights Watch

Tags: human-rights, war-crime, ngos

Are reports of *Human Rights Watch* reviewed by external authorities before they are published? Who verifies the veracity of the information present in their reports? Are evidences and citations presented in these reports audited?

Comment: Can you limit the scope of your questions?  It's pretty impossible to answer as is.  Do you have any particular reports in mind?

Comment: Yeah... Their reports on Kashmir.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  When were the reports published?  What were their titles?  Is there anything about them that might have been controversial?

Comment: Questions about the validity of one specific report would be a topic for [skeptics stackexchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com). However, the internal review practices of human rights organizations before they make a statement are on-topic here. But I would urge you to ask separate questions for separate organizations. Also, the question "Were there any controversies in the past regarding publications of Human Rights Watch and Amnesty?" is far too broad. Stirring up controversy is part of their business.

Comment: Different organizations have different quality assurance practices. I reduced the question to one of the two organizations you mentioned to keep the scope manageable. You might want to open a second question about Amnesty International. I removed the "was there any controversy" part because pretty much every report by a human rights organization generates some controversy. When this part was important to you, you might want to make it more specific, like for example asking about cases where reports they made turned out to be undeniable flat out wrong.

Comment: How is your question related with politics?

Comment: I wanted to know if these reports could be politically motivated. These reports are cited in Wikipedia articles. The organisation gets funding from various countries, so some countries could give some extra $'s to promote their agenda maybe?

Comment: There is a difference between "The organization gets funding from [private citizens and organizations] from various countries" and "The organization gets funding from [governments and government controlled organizations] from various countries." What are you claiming? Hint: https://www.hrw.org/financials

Comment: @Rathony - because both HRW and AI are intensely political organizations, AND their findings are used for political purposes beyond their own intentions as well

Comment: @SJuan76 that much explanation would be off topic for my question. I think user4012's comment suffices.

Comment: @user4012 So? Is asking "Are reports of Human Rights Watch reviewed by external authorities before they are published?" on-topic? Are reports of U.N.'s organizations reviewed by external authorities? Are reports of a US senate committee reviewed by external authorities?

Comment: You seem to claim that funding is influencing the way HRW reports are writting, so researching HRW funding is as on-topic as it can be; otherwise do not make comments about "some countries could give extra $'s to promote their agenda" if you do not want those comments challenged with facts.

Comment: And for @user4012 comment, I understand he means "political" in the broad sense of "study or practice of the distribution of power and resources within a given community (a usually hierarchically organized population) as well as the interrelationship(s) between communities" (Wikipedia), which makes the question on-topic here (and I agree). If he were suggesting that HRW reports are manipulated to support a political position, he should be writting an answer and documenting his sources for that affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

> Are reports of Human Rights Watch reviewed by external authorities before they are published?

They probably try, but it's often not possible to determine if testimony is authentic or not. [The New York Times has an article](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/10/20/opinion/20bernstein.html?_r=1&em) in which the founder of Human Rights Watch, R.L. Bernstein, explains the difficulty:

> But how does Human Rights Watch know that these laws have been violated? In Gaza and elsewhere where there is no access to the battlefield or to the military and political leaders who make strategic decisions, it is extremely difficult to make definitive judgments about war crimes. Reporting often relies on witnesses whose stories cannot be verified and who may testify for political advantage or because they fear retaliation from their own rulers.

If they have additional evidence to back up some claim I'm sure they put it in (if at all possible) because that improves their report. If there is no additional evidence mentioned in the report / article then I think you should assume the worst: a single source that has not been verified.